# ftp_delete(): Warning because of disk space on ftp(?)

Tags: php, ftp

I've got the feeling that this is quite a dumb question because the error message is so simple (yet so mysterious for me):

**"PHP Warning:  ftp_delete(): Used 70077.83MB from 256000.00MB."**

It seems, the deletion of the file still took place.
I don't see a problem here. Disk space is never a problem when you delete a file, right?
I am not even sure what these sizes refer to. The deleted file had a size of about 420MB.
Googling didn't help me. The phrase "ftp_delete(): Used" didn't return any results.

edit: ftp_delete() returned false.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: Actually, some ftp servers *do* prevent you from deleting when your quota is exceeded. Stupid feature because you *can* overwrite a file with an empty one to free space but as you can see the message might make sense. Besides that, I think that message is shown whenever the ftpd sends it.

Comment: That looks more like a memory warning for your PHP instance rather than an error code from ftp_delete. Is that a possibility?

Comment: I've seen memory errors. They are like "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 16777216 bytes exhausted"

Answer (score 2):

Here's the relevant PHP source ([`/ext/ftp/ftp.c`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/tags/php_5_4_0/ext/ftp/ftp.c?revision=323659&view=markup)):

```
int
ftp_delete(ftpbuf_t *ftp, const char *path)
{
    if (ftp == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (!ftp_putcmd(ftp, "DELE", path)) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (!ftp_getresp(ftp) || ftp->resp != 250) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Since the command is executed successfully, a plausible explanation is that the server returns a [code other than 250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes) (although still in the 2xx range). To solve the mystery you 'll probably have to manually connect with an FTP client and see what exactly is returned.

Comment: It returned "250 DELE command successful". Maybe the circumstances were different.

Comment: @Leif: You 'll definitely need to make this reproducible on demand first if the answer is to be found.

Comment: I did as you recommended and connected manually. It's not really a surprise that I didn't get a php warning here. ;)